# Access STEP Instance ID's with PythonOCC

Tags: python, cad, step, opencascade, pythonocc

Let's suppose I'm using this STEP file data as input:

```
#417=ADVANCED_FACE('face_1',(#112),#405,.F.);
#418=ADVANCED_FACE('face_2',(#113),#406,.F.);
#419=ADVANCED_FACE('face_3',(#114),#407,.F.);
```

I'm using [pythonocc-core](https://github.com/tpaviot/pythonocc-core) to read the STEP file.
Then the following code will print the names of the `ADVANCED_FACE` instances (`face_1`,`face_2` and `face_3`):

```py
from OCC.Core.STEPControl import STEPControl_Reader
from OCC.Core.TopExp import TopExp_Explorer
from OCC.Core.TopAbs import TopAbs_FACE
from OCC.Core.StepRepr import StepRepr_RepresentationItem

reader = STEPControl_Reader()
tr = reader.WS().TransferReader()
reader.ReadFile('model.stp')
reader.TransferRoots()
shape = reader.OneShape()


exp = TopExp_Explorer(shape, TopAbs_FACE)
while exp.More():
    s = exp.Current()
    exp.Next()

    item = tr.EntityFromShapeResult(s, 1)
    item = StepRepr_RepresentationItem.DownCast(item)
    name = item.Name().ToCString()
    print(name)
```

How can I access the identifiers of the individual shapes? (`#417`,`#418` and `#419`)

### Minimal reproduction

https://github.com/flolu/step-occ-instance-ids

Comment: I could not run your code successfully. What OCC version you have? Could you run and share the output of your code, please? Thanks!

Comment: @IamAshKS I've added a minimal reproduction

Comment: Please do not put links to code inside the question post it directly.

Comment: @dosas The code is in the question, but the repository also contains a STEP file, which is needed to run the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a STEP model after `reader.TransferRoots()` like this:

```py
model = reader.StepModel()
```

And access the ID like this in the loop:

```
id = model.IdentLabel(item)
```

The full code looks like this and can also be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/flolu/step-occ-instance-ids):

```py
from OCC.Core.STEPControl import STEPControl_Reader
from OCC.Core.TopExp import TopExp_Explorer
from OCC.Core.TopAbs import TopAbs_FACE
from OCC.Core.StepRepr import StepRepr_RepresentationItem

reader = STEPControl_Reader()
tr = reader.WS().TransferReader()
reader.ReadFile('model.stp')
reader.TransferRoots()
model = reader.StepModel()
shape = reader.OneShape()


exp = TopExp_Explorer(shape, TopAbs_FACE)
while exp.More():
    s = exp.Current()
    exp.Next()

    item = tr.EntityFromShapeResult(s, 1)
    item = StepRepr_RepresentationItem.DownCast(item)

    label = item.Name().ToCString()
    id = model.IdentLabel(item)

    print('label', label)
    print('id', id)
```

Thanks to [temurka1](https://github.com/temurka1) for pointing [this](https://github.com/tpaviot/pythonocc-core/issues/1119#issuecomment-1231562360) out!

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to run your code due to issues installing the pythonocc module, however, I suspect that you should be able to inspect the StepRep_RepresentationItem object (prior to string conversion) by traversing `__dict__` on it to discover/access whatever attributes/properties/methods of the object you may need:

```
    entity = tr.EntityFromShapeResult(s, 1)
    item = StepRepr_RepresentationItem.DownCast(entity)
    
    print(entity.__dict__)
    print(item.__dict__)
```

If necessary the `inspect` module exists to pry deeper into the object.

## References

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__

https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html

https://github.com/tpaviot/pythonocc-core/blob/66d6e1ef6b7552a1110a90e86a1ed34eb12ecf16/src/SWIG_files/wrapper/StepElement.pyi

Comment: Unfortunately it seems as if `entity` and `item` are just pointers. The prints log the following: `{'this': <Swig Object of type 'Standard_Transient *' at 0x7f2733b9e900>}` and `{'this': <Swig Object of type 'StepRepr_RepresentationItem *' at 0x7f2733b9e990>}`

Comment: @Flo I see, this makes sense, considering the python interface files. What do you get with `dir(entity)` and `dir(item)`? I'm willing to chat offline concerning this—this question seems entirely solvable, but I'm not able to get it running on my machine.

Comment: @Flo, also, I found that you may be able to dump the object to a string `.DumpToString()` or json `.DumpJsonToString()`. https://github.com/tpaviot/pythonocc-core/blob/e8af62e79b9c0449ea04f08b6d70b8edf5f54675/test/core_wrapper_features_unittest.py#L728 it's also worth inspecting the corresponding cpp interface files.

Comment: `dir()` doesn't contain information about the id. I would be glad to chat privately! Then we could also fix your problem with not being able to run the code. And `.DumpToString()` does only work for the shape, but doesn't contain information about the id, too.

Comment: @Flo Are you able to invite me to a chat. I'm having trouble inviting you. Or we can just chat in the Python section—just @ me.

Comment: I'm not sure where the chat is

Comment: Where would you like to chat?

Comment: @Flo I messaged you in the Python channel of SO chat. Just respond with the time in GMT you want to sync.